# Is there any way to shop after the start of the Depths of Mementos dungeon?

Tags: persona-5

*Spoilers ahead*

I'm after the Holy Grail and 'Good ending' cutscenes and now I'm having a hard time.

The Depths of mementos has pretty much sucked me dry of SP Recovery items, and that makes the climb that comes after pretty hard. My way of playing seems to need a lot of healing, and my build makes Morgana and Makoto my only good healers.

Late in the climb, I'm starting to be pretty low in SP, and I just game over'ed at what I think was the last regular ennemy before the final boss.

I'm now back down at the start of that climb. I have a lot of money from the Depths of Mementos, but can't seem to spend it somewhere to buy, let's say, some SP recovery items (or even some better equipement, that could help too.)

So is there a way to shop for items after you started the Depths of Mementos, or will I have to just play as conservative as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are:

1. Use the map to travel to Depths Entrance.
2. Exit to Path of Iweleth
3. Use the map to travel to Mementos Entrance.
4. Exit.

As someone on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Persona5/comments/c24idb/mementos_depths/) has pointed out, the only two shops available to you now are the Airsoft Shop and the Clinic. Once you are done at either location, you will immediately be returned to Mementos.
According to [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/persona-5/Depths_of_Mementos), this will not work after you've passed the second Safe Room.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I could see, there is no way to go out and buy items after you started the Depths of Mementos.

But, when you are starting the Final Palace, there is the girl in blue next to the velvet room door that can give you a full HP/SP Heal anytime you want.

You can also teleport from the door to the final boss back to the start of the Final Palace, where you can do the full heal before starting the final boss.